# Error when sending email on Heroku

Tags: python, heroku, gmail

I've developed a web app in python and I'm interested in getting the users to send me a message by email.

In order to do that I've used this function

```
def send_email(user, pwd, recipient, subject, body):
    import smtplib
    #
    gmail_user = user
    gmail_pwd = pwd
    FROM = user
    TO = recipient if type(recipient) is list else [recipient]
    SUBJECT = subject
    TEXT = body
    #
    # Prepare actual message
    message = """From: %s\nTo: %s\nSubject: %s\n\n%s
    """ % (FROM, ", ".join(TO), SUBJECT, TEXT)
    server = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
    server.ehlo()
    server.starttls()
    server.login(gmail_user, gmail_pwd)
    server.sendmail(FROM, TO, message)
    server.close()
```

To send to my gmail address the user response. This work well when deploying the app locally. But when I deploy the app on Heroku I get an Internal Server Error on screen, but I can't really see an error message on the logs.

I also got an email from google saying that they blocked an attempt to log in and I guess it was from the Heroku server.

I'm not sure how to move forward.

Comment: Did you allow less secure apps to your gmail? https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en

Comment: You probably need to allow access for less secure apps in your Google account settings.

Comment: I turned on access for less secure apps, but the problem still persists.

Comment: As an alternative solution, do you know of any other email provider that could be better to use instead of Google? I expect no more than 50 emails to be sent, but I need something that is not as hard to bypass as Gmail.

Comment: Hello, was you able to find a solution for the problem ? I am having the same problem